# How to use xcopy to copy directories with specific prefix to another folder

Tags: windows, command-line, shell, batch-file

I have a folder A and it contains a lot of sub-directories with name like `2017-mm-dd` and `2018-mm-dd`, the sub-directory is not empty and what inside it is also to be copied.

So here comes the question, how to copy 2018-mm-dd sub-directories to B folder with `xcopy` command on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to accomplish this with `xcopy`, `dir /b` and `for` in simple scenarios, but when I set up a complex test, it failed. `xcopy` is simply too old and outdated.

I recommend using PowerShell instead. The following PowerShell command gives you what you want.

```
Copy-Item "2018-*" C:\ -Force -Recurse
```

In fact, I advise ditching Command Prompt and batch files altogether. They belong to 1990s. PowerShell and its .ps1 are the way to go.

Comment: After struggling with windows batch file, I couldn't agree with your ideas more.

Comment: You remind me of my own struggling. I fell in love with PowerShell very fast. In it, the output is always a programmatic object that you can manipulate in several ways. Very maneuverable. And since Command Prompt is just dying out, I suggest you visit Microsoft Academy and take some quick free PowerShell courses.

Comment: Thanks for the kind reminder. Not touch MS frequently but the experience to Windows Batch file is like a nightmare. Powershell is the first option next time.